# “make: protoc: Command not found” while installing grpc from source

Tags: c++, makefile, protocol-buffers, grpc, opensuse

I have cloned this repository `https://github.com/grpc/grpc.git` for installing the grpc. I want to use the framework with `C++` programming so I followed the instructions given in folder `src/cpp`.

To build grpc for C++ from the source (in OpenSUSE) there are some pre-requisites *[given in this link](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/BUILDING.md)*

```
 $ [sudo] apt-get install build-essential autoconf libtool pkg-config
```

As mentioned, to build from source and run tests, one needs

```
$ [sudo] apt-get install libgflags-dev libgtest-dev
$ [sudo] apt-get install clang libc++-dev
```

I could not find any `build-essential`, `libgflags-dev` and `libgtest-dev`. I don't know whether this is the reason for not getting grpc installed.

Later,
I have manually installed protocol buffer compiler `protoc` before running the  `make`.

When I run `make` in the grpc root directory. I get this error

```
[PROTOC]  Generating protobuf CC file from src/proto/grpc/channelz/channelz.proto
make: protoc: Command not found
make: *** [Makefile:2601: /home/rohan/Downloads/grpc/gens/src/proto/grpc/channelz/channelz.pb.cc] Error 127
```

Unable to figure out why this error is showing as I already have installed `protoc`. Is some linking problem, then please share how to solve it. I am new to Linux so I really am a little bit hesitant to change and `env` file or some `make` file by my own.

Please suggest some help. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Where did you manually install `protoc`? In a path that is in your `PATH` I hope?

Comment: Hi @MatthieuBrucher I have no `PATH` set in `.bashrc`. Is that what you are asking? that said, I think protobuff is installed in some default location, say `/usr/include` and `/usr/lib64`. **How do I make sure of it though?** also when I do `protoc --IPATH` it gives **Missing value for flag: --IPATH**

Comment: You will have to figure this out, because the path but be added to the environment variable `PATH`. Not sure what you think `protoc -IPATH` is supposed to do.

Comment: If you type `which protoc`, it will search your `PATH`, and tell you where it is installed, if it can find it.

Comment: Hi @NickODell and @MatthieuBrucher, This was definitely `protobuf` installation problem. As I reinstalled the protobuff again this problem was solved. apparently I downloaded erroneous git repo which is now fixed. *Since I am new to SO I don't know how to close this Issue without any answer.*

Comment: We only close questions if the question cannot be answered. (E.g. "Is cereal a soup?") Write an answer to your question, so the next person to have this problem knows how to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have resolved this problem by installing protocol buffer compiler **properly**.

The important step which I forgot to do earlier is to update the submodules with `git submodule update --init --recursive` when you are building protoc with git repository.

The steps for C++ version are mentioned at [this link](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/tree/master/src).

Thanks,